# htaccess pattern match from both RewriteCond and RewriteRule

Tags: apache, .htaccess

What I'm trying to achieve is to forward `api.example.com/index.html` to `example.com/dashboard/index.html`, but in a portable way, without hardcoding either the domain name or the page name into the .htacess file, so that it would also work to forward `api.mydomain.com/main.html` to `mydomain.com/dashboard/main.html`.

What I've tried so far is:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^api\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/dashboard/$1 [R=302,L]
```

But this seems to include an unwanted `api` in the resulting URL:

```
example.com/dashboard/api/index.html
```

What am I doing wrong?

Also, how do I keep the original URL in the address bar, so that it remains as `api.example.com/index.html` even if the underlying page being served is `example.com/dashboard/index.html`?

Comment: What folder is your htaccess file located in?

Comment: The `.htaccess` file is in the top level (public html) folder.  It is clearly taking effect, but not quite doing what I want it to do.  And, if I replace `$1` with a hardcoded `index.html` then it works fine... i.e. redirects to `example.com/dashboard/index.html` (without the extra `api` in the path).

Comment: Does your uri contain `api` in the beginning ? I mean the uri you are going to is something like `/api/index.html` ?

Comment: No, as stated in the question, the working uri is `/dashboard/index.html` but the htaccess rule forwards to `/dashboard/api/index.html`.  The spurious `api` seems to be picked up from the subdomain `api` via the regexp pattern match from `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^api\.(.+)$` but I don't understand why that ends up in the path part of the forwarded url.

Comment: The `api` path in your destination url is not being added by the RewriteCond regex . But I think your subdomain url is adding it internally because your subdomain points to that folder.

Comment: Genius... that's it.  Sorry, I hadn't appreciated that when you create a subdomain it is associated with a folder... the default folder for `api` is `/public_html/api` when created, but if I set a custom folder of `/public_html/dashboard` then it works... though with a modified `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1` (no need to specify `dashboard/` because that is added automatically.  Thanks!  *ALSO...* regarding the final part of the question, how do I keep `api.example.com/index.html` in the address bar... rather than actually forwarding completely?  (P.S. if you add an answer, I'll accept it)

Comment: OK, so I've learned a lot from this question.  Given that a subdomain is associated with a folder, it seems to be automatic that requests at the top level of the subdomain are directed to that folder.  So probably I've learned that, to achieve what I want, I don't have to mess with htaccess at all, and just set up the subdomain folder correctly.